# Generate Routes in Symfony Command Class

Tags: symfony, routes, command

I am using Symfony 4.2.1 and I cannot somehow not use the generate() Method of router:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class NewAcceptedOrderCommand extends Command
{

/**
 * @var RouterInterface $router
 */
private $router;


public function __construct(
    RouterInterface $router
) {
    $this->router = $router;

    parent::__construct();
}

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('address:new')
        ->setDescription('Get adresses by Status ID')
        ->setHelp('Get adresses by Status ID')
        ->addArgument('id', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Status ID');

}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('adresses_index');
    // SOME more Code
}

}
```

I injected all sorts of other services and interfaces before (EntityManagerInterface, my Logservice etc.)

But I am always getting

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "adresses_index" as such
>   route does not exist.

But this route exists for sure I checked with  **php bin/console debug:router** and also using it in other places. I am using the global approach from here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally

Comment: Sure you did not spell address wrong? adresses_index

Comment: No, it was autofill from the symfony plugin in phpstorm and I also tried simple ones like index etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was thinking to secure at the beginning and added the annotation "method" to every action - it has to be unset (ANY). It works fine afterwards.

Comment: Actually I was using the wrong route... Since I got EN and DE as languages it only knew routes like adresses_index.de and adresses_index.en - and I found no solution by setting a locale which the mail template twig file use later (like a Context or smth). So now I get the locale in the Mailservice and pass it to the Twig view and create the route there. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to configure your router

```
$context = $this->router->getContext();
$context->setHost($this->container->getParameter('router_host'));
$context->setScheme($this->container->getParameter('router_scheme'));
```